# Adding ternary operator to IF Cookie

Tags: php, cookies

I was told I had to add a ternary operator to make my conditional work.
Am a newb so not really sure how to do that.

```
<div id="notification-container">
<div id="notification">'.if(isset($_COOKIE['HotspotUserEmail'])){$m01}else{$m03}.'<div id="secondary">'.$m04.'</div>
</div></div>
```

What I am trying to achieve is, if cookie is present I want the contents of the first variable to be display. If there isn't one, I want the else to be.

Comment: I *really* love it when my comments gets ignored. (I probably guess you don't print this html with php as I guessed in your last question, if you would read my comments)

Comment: I do print it. Yes. I echo the a few lines of html that change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just marshall your variable ahead of time:

```
<?
  $mVar = (isset($_COOKIE['HotspotUserEmail'])) ? $m01 : $m0;
?>
<div id="notification-container">
<div id="notification">'{$mVar}'</div>
</div>
```

N.B. I'm assuming you're using something that is echoing `$mVar` like a Smarty template. It's unclear from your original question if you're echoing the `div` parts and trying to in-line template logic or something else. `'{$mVar}'` won't work without some sort of templating, you'd have to `<?php echo $mVar;?>`

If you're doing this entirely inside a php script, this is what you want:

```
$mVar = ;
echo "<div id="notification-container"><div id="notification">".$mVar."</div></div>";
```

Or inline:

```
echo "<div id="notification-container"><div id="notification">".((isset($_COOKIE['HotspotUserEmail'])) ? $m01 : $m0)."</div></div>";
```

Comment: It doesn't work. This is what I have: <div id="notification-container"> <div id="notification">'.if(isset($_COOKIE['HotspotUserEmailUNIROYAL'])) ? $m01 : $m03;.'<div id="secondary">'.$m04.'</div> </div></div>

Comment: What is your output? Also I note you're NOT marshaling ahead of the fact. Your statement above will quit after the ternary operator because you include a `;`.

Comment: Error is: syntax error, unexpected T_IF. I tried with";" and without. Still can't get it to work. As for the variables, they are set priorly. So I am just trying to show their value, if the cookie is present.

Comment: Argh, sorry: see update. Just elide the `if`.

Comment: There is another problem now. The variable contents are displayed, however. There is another div, following after the html I posted. And that gets cut off. Is there a fix for that?

Comment: That sounds like another problem that we have no context on. I would note that you aren't including *compileable* code for us to examine. See http://www.sscce.org/

Comment: For example, not even `<div id="secondary">'.$m04.'</div>` is displayed. Everything past just gets cut off. Am I missing something?

Comment: Note that the code you *just* provided **will not compile**. You HAVE to give us examples that will compile so we can check what we're giving you. That means *more code* around what you're showing us.

Comment: I fixed it by added parenthesis around the conditional, like this: `(isset($_COOKIE['HotspotUserEmail']) ? $m01 : $m03)`; is this approach correct?

Comment: Does it work? Also don't forget to reward the people helping you: Mike gave you an answer worth upvoting.

Comment: Yeah, it does work with the parenthesis

Answer (score 2):

You would replace your `if (conditional) { statement; } else {statement; }` with something like this:

```
isset($_COOKIE['HotspotUserEmail']) ? $m01 : $m03
```

Comment: It doesn't work. This is what I have: `<div id="notification-container"> <div id="notification">'.if(isset($_COOKIE['HotspotUserEmailUNIROYAL'])) ? $m01 : $m03;.'<div id="secondary">'.$m04.'</div>
</div></div>`

Comment: you have an extra if in there. please re-read the answer and I also suggest check out the PHP manual